# Interior of difference of two convex sets

Tags: convex-analysis

Let $A, B$ be two nonempty convex set in normed space $X$. We always have
$$
\text{int}(A)\bigcap B\ne\emptyset\;\Longrightarrow\; 0\in\text{int}(A-B).
$$
Indeed, suppose that $\text{int}(A)\bigcap B\ne\emptyset$. Let $u\in\text{int}(A)\bigcap B$. Then there exists $r>0$ such that $B(u;r)\subset A$. Then
$0\in B(u;r)-\{u\}\subset A-B$. Hence $0\in\text{int}(A-B)$. The reverse implication is not true in general. Indeed, let $A=\{0\}, B=X$. Then $\text{int}(A)\bigcap B=\emptyset$ but $0\in X=\text{int}(A-B)$.

**Question** Sufficient conditions on $A, B$ to have
$$
\text{int}(A)\bigcap B\ne\emptyset\;\Longleftrightarrow\; 0\in\text{int}(A-B).
$$

**My attemption** We hope we can use this equivalence
$$
\text{int}(A)\bigcap B\ne\emptyset\;\Longleftrightarrow\; 0\in\text{int}(A)-B.
$$
to solve my problem.

Thank you for all kind help and comments.

Answer (score 0):

If convex set $B$ contains more than one point, there is a convex set $A$ with empty interior such that $0 \in \text{int}(A-B)$.  Namely, if $b_1, b_2 \in B$, let $f$ be a continuous linear functional such that $f(b_1) \ne f(b_2)$, and let
$A = \{x: f(x) = (f(b_1) + f(b_2))/2$.

This shows that your conditions would have to involve $A$ as well as $B$.

Comment: Could you make clear your answer?

Comment: What part of it don't you understand?